# Получать данные о корректности дампа базы в zabbix

Tags: mysql, linux, zabbix

Мне нужно автоматизировать получение данных о корректности создания копий бекапов **mysql**. Т.е. исключить нулевые размеры, поврежденные файлы и т.п. И потом ответ выводить в *zabbix*, к примеру, 0 или 1. Дампы делаю средствами `mysqldump`, через **bash**-скрипт.

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста: уточните, что у вас уже есть, и с чем именно возникли проблемы.

Comment: есть скрипт который делает дамп.  я хочу убедиться в том что бекапы получаются без проблем. я хочу проверять целостность архива, наличие его размера больше 100 кб(к примеру), и если всё ок записать в файл еденичку, и потом передать это в заббикс. Если дампа нет, он поврежден, либо весит мало получать 0.

Comment: как вы проверяете «целостность архива»?

Comment: Попробуйте наливать получившийся бекап на другую машинку.

Comment: проверять целостность можно средствами архиватора, zcat к примеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как вариант:**

1. На стороне сервера Bash-скрипт который проверяет валидность дампа и возвращает 1 или 0
2. В клиенте zabbix выдаляете отдельный `UserParameter` с item'ом который возвращает 1 или 0

например:

```
UserParameter=checkIntegrity,/path/to/bash-script.sh
```

в самом простом случае: 1 - все отлично, 0 - все плохо

3. Zabbix сервере добавляете item и trigger с вашей логикой